# Flutter HomeScreen(this.user) - Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

good day my fellow coders
I have a little problem where I am running firebase auth and cloud firestore in a flutter app with a curved nav bar.
Now here is my problem on `home_screen.dart` file I had to add 3 things in order to get my crud function to work see code below:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  User user;
  HomeScreen(this.user);
  
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(........
```

Now within `my main_screen` where my curved navigation bar is situated there is a `_pageOption = []` there see below:

```
class _mainScreenState extends State<mainScreen> {

int _page = 0;

  final _pageOption = [

     add pages here

      HomeScreen(),
      AddCardScreen(),

  ];
```

Where i have the issue is everything is imported and works fine however when i pass this.user on the `HomeScreen()`, as it should be then I receive the Error:

> Can't access 'this' in a field initializer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside  `HomeScreen()` you already specify the required parameter `User user` Because of that when you init `HomeScreen` its throws an error.

So for solution, you can set User in HomeScreen as null-check operator.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

    User? user;  // null check operator ?
    HomeScreen(this.user);
}
```

Via this error will be cleared but before access user must check whether its null or not is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for that but maybe I wasnt to clear in my message.. the problem isnt on the HomeScreen the problem is on the mainScreen() where my curved navigation bar is, because when i add User? user to HomeScreen i am required to pass a parameter in the mainScreen final _pageOption = [ HomeScreen(),  ] and if i add user as parameter it still doesnt initialize

Comment: i got your problem, You want to send the user to homescreen but it's not initiated, Can you update question where do you get user.

Comment: Yes, Check this, It must be defined in HomeScreen constructor like this.

Comment: i mean where do you set the value of the user from API or firebase or something like that.